# DBReader supplies length of string instead of string

Tags: c#

Currently my issue is that when I run the code it shows a datagrid with the `length` of the Forename Rather Than the Forename itself. Anyone got any clues, seems very silly.

```
List<string> NameList = new List<string>();
string connectionString = "Server = localhost; Database = TestDb; Trusted_Connection = True;";
try
    {
    IDbConnection dbcon;
    using (dbcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        dbcon.Open();
        using (IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand())
        {
            string sql = "Select * from people";
            dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
            using (IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string FirstName = (string) reader["ForeName"];
                    NameList.Add(FirstName);
                }
                DataGrid1.ItemsSource = NameList.ToList();
                reader.Close();
                dbcon.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: when you debug the code, assuming that you are using the debugger; what is the value of `NameList[0]` also don't you need to call `DataGrid1.DataBind()`; before the reader.Close()

Comment: NameList[0] = "Sharon"

Comment: are you familiar with `BindingList` there is also another way you can do this you could create a class with auto property's match the field names that you want.. load the BindingList then assign the DataGrid1.DataSource = to that BindingList very simple I use it all the time.. personally I would refactor your code, create a stored procedure and return the data into a DataSet or DataTable and bind it that way.. how many columns are you trying to display on the dataGrid..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `List<string>` to something like the following below

```
IList<string> NameList = new List<string>();
DataGrid1.DataSource = NameList.Select(s => new 
                       { 
                           Value = s 
                       }).ToList();
```

something along these lines doesn't hurt to try

Comment: Worked Perfectly, Is there a way to avoid the linq expression? Just out of curiousity. Thank you again.

Comment: there are many ways to skin a cat so to speak.. and if you are not familiar with using linq.. I would just bind my datagrid to a DataTable or a DataSet, and if you use EF you could still bind the data from a List<Object> try to google different ways to bind data to a DataGrid or DataGridView

Comment: Glad I could provide you with an alternative solution